# How do I pull a payload after the response to the client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

This is current code..

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flowForHandlingPlainEncryptHistory() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(InputWithPlainEncryptHistory())
            .handle(ENCRYPT_HISTORY_SERVICE, EXTRACT_ENCRYPT_HISTORY)
            .channel(outputWithPlainStringOfXml()).get();
}
```

Methods that work in ENCRYPT_HISTORY
The INSERT into the DB and returns a success.

However, in order to improve speed
Unconditional return success, and then try to INSERT a DB.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flowForHandlingPlainEncryptHistory() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(InputWithPlainEncryptHistory())
            .handle(ENCRYPT_HISTORY_SERVICE, "extractEncryptHistoryReturn")
            .channel(outputWithPlainStringOfXml()
            .handle(ENCRYPT_HISTORY_SERVICE, "extractEncryptHistoryInsert").get();
}

@Override
public Object extractEncryptHistoryReturn(Object payload) throws Exception {
    log.debug("[INFO] extractEncryptHistoryReturn payload : {}", payload.toString());

    Map<String, Object> result = initResult();

    result.put(Constant.KEY_NAME_RESULT_CODE, Constant.CODE_SUCCESS);
    result.put(Constant.KEY_NAME_RESULT_MSG, Constant.MSG_SUCCESS);

    return result;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void extractEncryptHistoryInsert(Object payload) throws Exception {
    log.debug("[INFO] extractEncryptHistoryInsert payload : {}", payload.toString());

    Map<String, Object> params = initParam(payload);

    try {
        long headerInfoSeq = insertHeaderInfo(params);
        insertHeaderAclList(headerInfoSeq, (String) params.get("ACL_COUNT"), (String) params.get("ACL_LIST"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("[ERROR] extractEncryptHistory : Insert errors in the header information and acl list. {}", e.toString());
    }
}
```

`extractEncryptHistoryInsert` payload coming to the method is not of the first payload.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need a publish subscribe channel with each handler being a subscriber to it. Add a task executor so the two handlers run in parallel.

You can either have two `IntegrationFlow`s starting with the same channel or use subflows in a single `IntegrationFlow` bean.